# testing submit button with selenium webDriver

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, junit4

My html form contains multipl html tags such `<form>`

My html file: myFile.html

```
<body>
        <div class="globalContainer">                              
            <div class="test1" id="formM" width="848" height="720" method="post" name="devis" onreset="return vider();">
                <div class="content-1" id="cadreGlob">  
                    <div id="contentForm">
                        <div class="preview">
                            <div class="left_col">
                                <fieldset id="haut">                    
                                    <label  class="labelForm" id="labelPriorite">label1:</label>
                                        <select id="selectPrio">
                                            <option value="labT">subLabel11</option>
                                            <option value="labP">subLabel12</option>
                                        </select><p></p>                                                                                                           
                                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                                        <label class="labelForm" id="labelFile1">label2:</label>
                                        <input  id="upload1" type="file" name="file[]" />
                                    </form>                             
                                </fieldset>                     
                            </div>                  
                            <div class="right_col">                                             
                                <fieldset id="haut">
                                    <form name="page">
                                        <label class="labelForm" for="cb" id="labelPopulation">lebel3:</label> 
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="cb" checked="checked" onclick="valid();showPop();" /><br />            
                                        <label class="labelForm" for="ta" id="labelMessage2">label4:</label> 
                                            <textarea disabled="true" id="ta" name="ta" cols="22" rows="9"></textarea>
                                        <label class="labelForm" id="labelFile2" >label5:</label>
                                        <input id="upload2" type="file" name="valider" id="butonParc" disabled="disabled"/>                              
                                    </form>                                               
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>              
                            <div class="left_col">
                            <p></p>
                                <fieldset id="bas">                 
                                    <label class="labelForm" id="labelServiceOp">label6:</label>
                                        <select id="selectServOp">
                                            <option value="def">subLabel61</option>
                                            <option value="sec">subLabel62</option>
                                        </select><p></p>                                                
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>              
                            <div class="right_col">
                                <p></p>
                                <fieldset id="bas">
                                    <label class="labelForm" id="labelAdressage" >label7:</label>
                                        <select name="ToutePopD" id="ToutePopD">
                                            <option value="toujours">subLabel71</option>
                                            <option value="parfois">subLabl72</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <select name="ToutePopA" id="ToutePopA">
                                            <option value="toujours">subLabl73</option>
                                            <option value="parfois">subLabel74</option>
                                        </select>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>                                            
                            <div class="right_col"><p></p>
                                <form action="submit.html" id="sub" name="formValid">
                                    <input type="submit" id="validation" value="validate" name="submit" />
                                </form> <p></p>                                                                                       
                                    <script>
                                    function vider()
                                    {
                                        document.getElementById("formM").value = "";
                                        return false;
                                    };
                                    </script>                                                                                   
                                <input type="reset" id="cancel" value="Cancel"name="reset" />
                            </div>                  
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>      
            </div>  
        </div>      
    </body>
```

My first problem
when i execute this command

```
...
...
this.driver.findElement(By.id("validation")).click();
...
...
```

My test is not switch to the url : submit.html

My submit.html

```
    <body>
        <h2><center>Form validation with Succee</center></h2>
    </body>
```

My second problem:

When i execute the following code, i have an error : `Unable to locate element : {"method":"id","selector":"sub"}`

```
public class SeleniumTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private final StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        final Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        this.baseUrl = properties.getProperty("base.url", "myIp:8080/project");
    }

    @Test
    public void firefoxTest() throws Exception {
        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        testSelenium();
        verifyValidation(this.baseUrl +"submit.html");
    }

    private void testSelenium() throws Exception {
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.driver.get(this.baseUrl + "myFile.html");
        new Select(this.driver.findElement(By.id("formM")).findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset[@id='haut']/select[1]"))).selectByVisibleText("subLabel11");
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys("myUrl\\myFile.txt");       
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("validation")).click();
    }
    private void verifyValidation(String urlValidation) {
        String submit =
                this.driver.findElement(By.id("sub")).getAttribute("action");
        if (submit == urlValidation) {assertEquals("url problem : ", submit, urlValidation);
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        this.driver.quit();
        final String verificationErrorString = this.verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(final By by) {
        try {
            this.driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (final NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
            final Alert alert = this.driver.switchTo().alert();
            final String alertText = alert.getText();
            if (this.acceptNextAlert) {
                alert.accept();
            } else {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
            return alertText;
        } finally {
            this.acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why WebDriver can not find my id ! ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Please post your full HTML and full script. Based on your provide HTML tag, it should be <input instead of input (you missed "<")

Comment: what's your html file name? is it submit.html? if it's not, does submit.html exist on your myIp:8080/project?

Comment: does submit.html exist on your myIp:8080/project? if it doesnot, then when you click validate button, you get something similar to "The requested URL could not be retrieved". On "The requested URL could not be retrieved" there is no "sub" ID element -> NoSuchElementExeption throws.  Try to put thread.sleep(10000) after get(validate).click() to see what you have

Comment: My submit.html exist in my myIP:8080/project. i tried to put Thread.sleep(10000) after driver.findElement(By.id("validation")).click(); but i have the same problem the page submit.html is not displayed and i have same error here: Unable to locate element {"method":"id","selector";"sub"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 2nd issue,

```
it comes into my mind, when there is no submit.html file on your server, page
not found displays. Then, on that page, there is no "id" element -> you get
NoSuchElement Exception throws
```

There are 4 issues in your scripts

```
1 - Your xpath //fieldset[@id='haut']/select[0] is not correct, xpath starts from [1]

2 - There is no label "subLabel11", only "subLabl11" exists

3 - this.driver.findElement(By.id("sub")).getAttribute("action"); will return *full-url* (In this case  myIp:8080/project/submit.html

4 - if (submit == urlValidation) will always return False since they are 2 objects in different memory location.

Suggest you change it to  if (submit.equals(urlValidation))
```

Beside these above notes, I run your script well on my machine and there is no issue. Here's my script:

```
new Select(browser.getBrowserCore().findElement(By.id("formM")).findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset[@id='haut']/select"))).selectByVisibleText("subLabl11");
browser.getBrowserCore().findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys("myUrl\\myFile.txt");       
browser.getBrowserCore().findElement(By.id("validation")).click();
String submit =
        browser.getBrowserCore().findElement(By.id("sub")).getAttribute("action");
System.out.println("submit: "+ submit);
if (!submit.equals("submit.html")) {
    System.out.println("comparator: FALSE");
};
```

Here's the test result

```
2014-07-21 18:13:44 [main]-[INFO] Started Browser
2014-07-21 18:13:44 [main]-[INFO] Pause 500 ms
2014-07-21 18:13:45 [main]-[INFO] Opened url: http://myIP:8305/
submit: http://myIP:8305/submit.html
comparator: FALSE
2014-07-21 18:13:51 [main]-[INFO] Pause 500 ms
2014-07-21 18:13:51 [main]-[INFO] Quitted Browser
PASSED: stackOverFlowTest

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: just ignore my browser.getBrowserCore, it's the same like your this.driver

Comment: i have changing my mistakes for labels "sublabel11"... and the xpath start. and i have tried your code but i have similar error:    Unable to locate element {"method":"id","selector";"sub"}

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the below code work fine with me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("Your URL");

        WebElement validate=driver.findElement(By.id("validation"));
        validate.click();

        driver.close();
    }
```

Following is the code for your 2nd question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("Your URL");

    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("selectPrio"));

    Select sel=new Select(element);
    sel.selectByVisibleText("subLabel12");


    driver.close();
}
```

Comment: it's the same thing I did, but I never see the submit.html page when the button is click submit

Comment: I am able to see submit.html page after clicking on Validate button.

Comment: not me i don't know why! for your second response it's not what i want to test submit button not select button

Comment: Though we have input tag there, which is not textbox enabled for entering some text, so i am hoping that is causing the problem. Can you just use click  this.driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).click();

Comment: i have no problem with this.driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).click();

Comment: I resolved my first problem (it was a problem with url of my submit.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for tracks you give me.
I finally succeeded to solve my problem
For my first problem:
I had a mistake in the URL of my page submit.html
For my second problem:
when I execute the command: this.driver.findElement this.driver.findElement(By.id("validation")).click();
the page myFile.html where there is my id "sub" is not supported by the driver but submit.html
And then I made the switch back to my original page myfile.html and I have no error.

Thank you again!